# I am trying to load my servlet in the browser and it gives me this error

Tags: java, html, xml, web-services, servlets

This is the error I see when I try to compile my code — am I passing the URL incorectly? I wanted to learn from this sample code to display my servlet in the browser.

```
HTTP Status 404 - /Lesson41/

type Status report

message /Lesson41/

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.22
```

My servlet code is as follows:

```
 import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    /**
     * Servlet implementation class Lesson41
     */

    @WebServlet("/Lesson41")
    public class Lesson41 extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */ 

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            String usersName = request.getParameter("YourName");

            String theLang = request.getParameter("Language");

            int firstNum = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Firstnum"));
            int secondNum = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("secondnum"));
            int sumONum = firstNum + secondNum;

            response.setContentType("text/html");

            PrintWriter output = response.getWriter();

            output.println("<html><body><h3>Hello " + usersName);

            output.println("</h3><br />" + firstNum + " + " + secondNum);
            output.println(" = " + sumONum + "<br />Speaks " + theLang + "</body></html>");
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            doGet(request, response);
        }

    }
```

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>HelloServers</display-name>
  <servlet> 
      <servlet-name>Lesson41</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>HelloServelets-Lesson41</servlet-class>
      </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>Lesson41</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>http://localhost:8080/Lesson41/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems that this : `http://localhost:8080/Lesson41/` url pattern is wrong, isnt url pattern suppose to be something like `/Lesson41/`?

Comment: i have tried that too still not working.

Comment: This is my current era HTTP Status 404 - /Lesson41/

type Status report

message /Lesson41/

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take following steps:

```
 1. Remove <Servlet> and <servlet-mapping> tags and anything in between them. Since you have used @WebServlet annotation. There is no need to declare those tags in web.XML.
```

2. In your form tag replace action attribute to:
   action="Lesson41"
3. Don't try to call the Servlet directly through the URL, you are posting some data with your request. First try to load your HTML page and then hit the submit button to call the Servlet's doPost() method.

Comment: What's the of your HTML/JSP file which has input tags?And what's the project name?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be multiple problems. As the error says

> Cannot connect to destination (localhost)

Most likely either your web server is not running or is not listening on 8080 port.

Secondly you seems to be missing your application context name in the URL:

```
 http://localhost:8080/Lesson41
```

Not sure what is your application but perhaps HelloServers and then URL should be:

```
 http://localhost:8080/HelloServers/Lesson41
```

Comment: I tried /Lesson41 and it gave me the same era. I am loading it via the web browser. My server is on.

Comment: Heye @Juned do you have an example of such to which i can learn from? or recommend?

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /Lesson41/

type Status report

message /Lesson41/

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.22